# Casting error when trying to use lambda expression to retrieve data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda

I'm using the code below to get a library record by Id

```
MIS3Entities context = new MIS3Entities();
DBLibrary library2 = context.DBLibraries.Find(q => q.ID == asset.ID);
```

It is throwing an error 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type'. I've tried different ways to cast this line but cannot get it to work. What do I need to change to get this line to work?

Comment: it seems that DBLibraries is a DbSet<DbLibrary>. in that case, Find method accepts an array of objects https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `First(OrDefault)`, `Single(OrDefault)` that accept a predicate as parameter,

the `DbSet<TEntity>.Find` Method only accept a `params Object[] keyValues` as parameter ([see documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx)) :

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values.

So in your case you can try something like that:

```
// Assuming that the asset.ID is the primary key of the DBLibrary table
DBLibrary library2 = context.DBLibraries.Find(asset.ID);
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault and SingleOrDefault are to be prefered over First or Singe, since they do not throw errors.

Comment: I disagree with you. There is a reason for that. If a result is expected may be you want the code to throw an exception rather than checking if the result is null

Comment: Totally agree - I should've written mostly (mostly = when you don't know if there are any with 100% certainity in normal behaviour).